# Is there an algorithm for moving ranges?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

In C++98, I can copy ranges with the `std::copy` algorithm.

```
std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), destination.begin());
```

Is there an algorithm in C++0x that moves the elements from source to destination? Or is `std::copy` somehow overloaded to accept something like rvalue iterators -- is there even such a thing?

The algorithm might look something like this:

```
#include <utility>

template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator mooove(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first, ++last) *result = std::move(*first);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Invoking the move assignment `operator=(T&&)` instead of the copy assignment `operator=(const T&)` for each element of the range.

Comment: so the algorithm will alter the source range, instead of copying -- it will 'cut' the elements?

Comment: It will potentially destroy the source elements, yes. That's how moving works in C++0x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be in the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n3000.pdf) (see section 25.3.2).

I have a hard copy of C++03 which is exactly the same as [C++98](http://www.ishiboo.com/~danny/c++/C++STANDARD-ISOIEC14882-1998.pdf) (sections 25.2.x) where you can see the same algorithms (without 'move' obviously).

Answer (score 2):

There is also an iterator adaptor, `std::move_iterator`, that can be used to adapt any range algorithm that makes copies to move the elements instead. `std::move(first, last, dest)` is just a convenience wrapper for the most common use case -- it is semantically equivalent to `std::copy(std::move_iterator(first), std::move_iterator(last), dest)`.

Comment: Ah, so there is indeed such a thing as an "rvalue iterator" :)

Answer (score 0):

Just because this page is a lil confusing right now… There is a `std::move( first, last, dest )`, OP was just confused by looking at an older C++0x draft. The function is defined by section 25.3.2.